# Data in Drop Down List Retrieve From DB in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In creating dropdown in my project encounters problems(errors). 
I'm very new to codeigniter.

Please check and advise what is wrong with with my code?

**Model**

```
Public function get_region()
{
    $return = array();
    $query  = $this->db->get('region')->result_array();
    if( is_array( $query ) && count( $query ) > 0 ){
    $return[''] = 'please select';
    foreach($query as $row)
    {
        $return[$row['id']] = $row['r_e_name'];
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('country_model');
    $data['countries'] = $this->country_model->get(false);
    $data['page_title']  = "Countries"; 
    $data['return']=$this->country_model->get_region();
    $this->template->show('countries', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_label('Region Name *', 'r_e_name'); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_dropdown('r_e_name', $return);?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Errors**

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: return

Filename: views/countries_add.php

Line Number: 17

---

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 331

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model

```
function get_country() {
    $return[''] = 'please select';
    $this->db->order_by('c_e_name', 'asc'); 
    $query = $this->db->get('country'); 
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
        $return[$row['id']] = $row['c_e_name'];
    }
    return $return;
}

function get_region(){
    $return[''] = 'please select';
    $query  = $this->db->get('region');
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
        $return[$row['id']] = $row['r_e_name'];
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('country_model');
    $data['country'] = $this->country_model->get_country();
    $data['region']  = $this->country_model->get_region();
    $data['page_title']  = "Countries";
    $this->template->show('countries', $data);
}
```

View

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo form_label('Country *', 'c_e_name'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo form_dropdown('c_e_name', $country);?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo form_label('Region Name *', 'r_e_name'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo form_dropdown('r_e_name', $region);?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The same errors show again even when i add "return $return;".

Comment: only one error occur foreach loop

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 331

Comment: it seems like the error is in this line $data['countries'] = $this->country_model->get(false);

Comment: I think foreach error come from 

   foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $return[$row['id']] = $row['r_e_name'];
    }

Comment: that method seems not returning valid array to be supplied in your dropdown, because I already tested the script and there is nothing wrong. Just comment that line and it will work fine.

Comment: can you also please post the method get in your model, in order for me to check the script. thanks..

Comment: This is the method get;
 
public function get($id = false)
 {
  if ($id) $this->db->where('id', $id);
  $this->db->order_by('c_e_name', 'asc');
  $get = $this->db->get('country');
  if($id) return $get->row_array();
  if($get->num_rows > 0) return $get->result_array();
  return array();
 }

Comment: I already updated my answer , please see above, thanks, don't forget to check if my solution is correct

Comment: Joni Demon, i will check "green mark". one more please. get() method is used to get data from "Country" table. get_region() method is used to get data from "Region" table. I also use get_region() method to display data from "Region" table in dropdown list. Please help me . thanks!

Comment: I already updated my answer, that script will get the country and region and display it in drop down option, if you only want to display the result from the model you can also send it to the view and display it using foreach

Answer (score 0):

You have not returned the result set from model. Just put

```
return $return;
```

at the end of your **function get_region()** in model.

Comment: The same errors show again even when i add "return $return;".

Comment: try changing your variable name as return is a reserved word